# frequency of each vector value in another vector matlab

Tags: matlab, frequency

I need to calculate the frequency of each value in another vector in MATLAB.
I can use something like

```
for i=1:length(pdata)
   gt(i)=length(find(pf_test(:,1)==pdata(i,1)));
end
```

But I prefer not to use loop because my dataset is quite large. Is there anything like [histc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) (which is used to find the frequency of values in one vector) to find the frequency of one vector value in another vector?

Answer (score 2):

If your values are only integers, you could do the following:

```
range = min(pf_test):max(pf_test);
count = histc(pf_test,range);

gt = count(ismember(range,a));
gt(~ismember(unique(a),b)) = 0;
```

If you can't guarantee that the values are integers, it's a bit more complicated. One possible method of it would be the following:

```
%restrict yourself to values that appear in the second vector
filter = ismember(pf_test,pdata);

% sort your first vector (ignore this if it is already sorted)
spf_test = sort(pf_test);

% Find the first and last occurrence of each element
[~,last] = unique(spf_test(filter));
[~,first] = unique(spf_test(filter),'first');

% Initialise gt
gt = zeros(length(pf_test));

% Fill gt
gt(filter) = (last-first)+1;
```

EDIT: Note that I may have got the vectors the wrong way around - if this doesn't work as expected, switch `pf_test` and `pdata`. It wasn't immediately clear to me which was which.

Answer (score 0):

You mention `histc`. Why are you not using it (in its version with two input parameters)?

```
>> pdata = [1 1 3 2 3 1 4 4 5];
>> pf_test = 1:6;
>> histc(pdata,pf_test)
ans =
     3     1     2     2     1     0
```